# Vista: "Change date and time" causes permissions error

Tags: windows-vista, uac, date-time

I double-click on the time in the bottom right to open the date and time panel. Then I click on the "Change date and time..." button (which has a shield) and I get the UAC dialog. I click "Continue", then am presented with an error that reads:

```
Unable to continue

You do not have permission to perform this task. Please
contact your computer administrator for help.
```

I will mention I have Comodo installed, but I have turned it off to test this out and I get the same results. All that I've found while googling were suggestions to turn UAC off, but I am interested in learning what the actual problem is.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I am a member of the Administrators group, which has both "Change the system time" and "Change the time zone" rights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, it's because you do not have administrator or power users rights. By default, only administrators and power users can change the date, time, or time zone. I like you to check [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300022) from MS.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I should have specified that I am a member of Administrators which has both "Change the system time" and "Change the time zone" rights. I will have a look at the KB link.